# How do I create an FTP share on Mac OS X Yosemite and access it from Windows 7 via FTP?

Tags: windows-7, macos, ftp

I am running JRiver Media Client/Server on a Windows 7 Ultimate box accessing media files shared on a MacPro running Yosemite (can also run Mavericks).  JRiver needs to be able to read and write to the shared folders on the Mac.    I want to use FTP for this as an alternative to SMB which does not work under Yosemite.  How do I configure this?

Answer (score 3):

You can activate the old ftp server via the terminal:

```
sudo -s launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist
```

And also disable it:

```
sudo -s launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist
```

There is also a software for this: http://www.troncept.com/lion-ftpd-enable/

Then, as far as I know, you have to share this directory in the system settings.

EDIT: You have to type in your user account and password from your mac in the Windows 7 network drive form.

Comment: You should have mentioned that... You have to type in your user account and password from your mac in the Windows 7 network drive form.

Comment: **comment from stanhend (see 2nd answer):**
Actually, I have Yosemite Server which allows me to turn on and share FTP. My problem is I can't get Win7 to recognize the FTP share on the Mac. I have turned on FTP services in Win7 and tried adding a network location through Windows Explorer with anonymous logon but it returns a permission/access denied message. I have read/write permissions set for everyone on the Mac side. I thought FTP was easy.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off SSH (remote login) in server.app->settings as it changes/enables/forces sftp connections only. That's likely what's failing for you. if you turn off remote login using SSH then it goes back to unecrypted ftp logins again.